# Do not track option for webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Is there a way to set the `WebView` to have:

> Do not track

option like Chrome app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Do not track" is actually an HTTP header (DNT). So you should be able to do this by adding that header to every request by way of [loadUrl(url, headers)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29). For example:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> extraHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
        extraHeaders.put("DNT", "1");
        view.loadUrl(url, extraHeaders); 
        return true;
    } 
});
```

Note that this loadUrl() overload requires API level 8.